# Unable to identify the purchased product in updatedTransactions delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a couple of products in IAP (in this example 2 of them) and I am using UITableView which the user will click and select which product they wanted to purchase. However I am not able to identify at the updatedTransactions delegate which transaction the user has purchased. Below are my codes:

```
NSArray *arrayProducts;

-(void) getProductInfo:(BLevelViewController *) viewController
{   
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
     _linkStatus.text = @"Able to purchase";        
     SKProductsRequest *requestProducts = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] 
     initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"example.1coin", @"example.2coin", nil]];
    requestProducts.delegate = self;
    [requestProducts start];

}else{
      _linkStatus.text = @"Please enable In App Purchase in Setting";
}    
}

-(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _linkStatus.text = @"Product loaded";
        arrayProducts = products;

    } else {
        _linkStatus.text = @"Product no found";
        arrayProducts = @[@"0",@"0"];
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }

}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

} else if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:1]];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.description isEqualToString:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:0]]){
                    [self unlockFeature1coin];
                }
                if ([transaction.description isEqualToString:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:1]]){
                    [self unlockFeature10coins];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BCoinsViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:coinsCellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.cellLabel.text = @"Buy 10 coins";
        [cell.cellButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.cellLabel.text = @"Buy 1 coin";
        [cell.cellButton setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The issue is at the lines below, what should I use as an identifier so that i can call different functions based on the user purchases?

```
        if ([transaction.description isEqualToString:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:0]]){
            [self unlockFeature1coins];
        }
        if ([transaction.description isEqualToString:[arrayProducts objectAtIndex:1]]){
            [self unlockFeature10coins];
        }
```

Comment: Where do you keep the information of the purchased products? And can you show the implementation `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? I think you are approaching this matter in an inappropriate way.

Comment: I have updated my codes with the cellForRowAtIndexPath. As I know Apple did not provide a generic method for the getProductInfo method, so we have to hard code the query, therefore in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, i have also hard coded 2 products (as an example). As I might not have approach this correctly, any advice I should handle this?

Comment: I would like to know a couple more things before I suggest you anything. Are your purchases non-consumable? If so then are you implementing a way to restore the purchases as this is an integral part of the in app purchases. In fact Apple WILL reject your app if you are not implementing a way to restore purchases.

Comment: Those are consumable products. Yea, I am aware that for non-consumable, we need to have a method to restore the purchase.

Comment: I get it. So when a purchase completes you just want to know which product it was, right? That's easy to find out. You can get the product identifier from the `SKPaymentTransaction` object like this `transaction.payment.productIdentifier`. If that's what you were looking for then I'll post it as an answer too.

Comment: Yea it works! From your advise with the transaction.payment.product.Identifier I just need to match with the exact hardcoded products. [transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"example.1coin"]. Thanks a lot for your help! :) Please post the answer for the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the product identifier from the `SKPaymentTransaction` object like this `transaction.payment.productIdentifier`. Just replace your if conditions with this code:

```
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"example.1coin"]){

        [self unlockFeature1coins];
    }
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"example.10coins"]){

        [self unlockFeature10coins];
    }
```

Comment: Adele Miraj, could you update your answer with the following code, incase others want used them directly. There is an issue to refer to the array products because they are not stored as an identifier. So the codes are shown as below. Thanks again for your help!  if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"example.1coin"]){
                    
                    [self unlockFeature1coins];
                }
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"example.10coins"]){

                    [self unlockFeature10coins];
                }